# Tutorial for moving from Java EE 5 to 6

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I'm looking for a quick tutorial to introduce me to the new features of Java EE 6.
I know the basics of JavaEE 5 servlets and JSPs etc (not an expert I must add. just the basics). So I don't want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2011/01/javaee5-vs-javaee6/) is a blog post where you can locate the differences and then just search for the new feature explicitly.